# Sparql-Plugin-Master Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to execute this plugin, and i got this error below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.BerlinDatasetTest
08:29:32.520 [main] WARN  o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Loading file:/Users/paulrocost/Downloads/sparql-plugin-master/target/test-classes/berlin_nt_100.nt: 
08:29:37.345 [main] WARN  o.o.rio.helpers.ParseErrorLogger - 'http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/vocabulary/USD' is not recognized as a supported xsd datatype. (9192, -1)
Results :

Tests in error: 
  loadAndClearRDFSelfRelationship(org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.BerlinDatasetTest): java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel
  org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPluginFunctionalTest: Starting neo server failed, see nested exception.
  executeInsert(org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPluginTest): java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel
  executeInsert(org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPluginTest)
  testLinkedData(org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPluginTest): java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel
  testLinkedData(org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPluginTest)

Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 6, Skipped: 2
```

Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: What sort of troubleshooting have you already done?

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed? Look at the warnings at the top of the message as it shows potential areas for issues.

Comment: I`m using jdk 1.7_25 on Mac 
I got the package on the git and made:
mvn clean package.

Comment: The error message indicates that you are not using Oracle JDK 7. What's the output `mvn -v`?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 14:31:09-0300)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the error. I ran with maven 3.1.0 and skiped the tests with "mvn package -DskipTests".
that way i got the neo4j-sparql-plugin-0.2-SNAPSHOT-server-plugin.zip. and unzipped on neo4j/plugins/sparql.
Thanks All.

Comment: This worked. And i could also insert quads using the "insert_quad" method as per the plugins's website. However, execute_sparql does not work.